# Is there any special configuration for mysql python django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to run the command
`bash ../download_content.sh create_django_tables`
but i got the error
**django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module. Did you install mysqlclient?**

Where as mysql-connector-python, mysql,mysql client are already  installed.

When i opened the mysql using mysql -u root -p
my database is already there,but its not migrating the tables.

I need help on this.
*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

Just install mysqlclient so Django can communicate with mysql

```
 pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I did this. It shows me the following error:    **
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.3.5)
WARNING: Running pip as root will break packages and permissions. You should install packages reliably by using venv: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv**

Comment: Share the settings and the bash script

Comment: Here is the settings :

Comment: ``` import os
from os.path import join
from django.conf import global_settings
import chat as project_module
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
INSTALLED_APPS = (
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.db.migrations',
 'chat',)
REDIS_PORT = 6379
REDIS_HOST ='localhost'
REDIS_DB = 0
CONCURRENT_THREAD_WORKERS = 10
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
  'ENGINE':  ' django.db.backends.mysql'
  'NAME': '',
  'USER': '',
  'PASSWORD': '',
  'HOST': 'localhost',
  'default-character-set': 'utf8',
  }
}```

Comment: Can you update your answer with the settings as it is NOT readable this way.

Comment: error remove by adding 2 line of code in __init__.py file. But now i am facing the error no module name Django.Whereas it is already installed. Do you have any idea how to remove this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you arent using any environment, use one, it makes your life easier
Secondly, follow this article [Medium](https://medium.com/@omaraamir19966/connect-django-with-mysql-database-f946d0f6f9e3) for the steps and a workaround, if it helps

Comment: Yes i am using environment. Plus i have done the same as your article but problem remains same. Further help needed.